# How to execute a Hangfire job every 14 days starting from a date

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I am able to log a fortnightly job using Hangfire,

```
if (vm.ReportInterval == 14)
                        {
                            reportFrequency = Cron.DayInterval(14);
                        }
```

This is working and doing it what it is supposed to do.

But What I want is to start the job on a particular date and then repeat every 14 days.

Essentially , need to pass a  second parameter to cron.DayInterval.

Example(This is not supported):

```
 if (vm.ReportInterval == 14)
               {
                  reportFrequency = Cron.DayInterval(14,new DateTime(2018,17,05));
               }
```

I looked at Cron class and it does not have a supported method to do so:

[image]

Is there another class on Hangfire to do the job?

The other way is to do a weekly job and then

- Pass custom parameters
- Check in method if needs to be executed (by date diff from last execution)
- Skip if Date diff is not 14 days

But I really do not want to go that way if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a RecurringJob that looks like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<IExportService>(
            "Export data",
            x => x.ExportToEmail(),
            "0 0 0 1/14 * ? *");
```

The important bit is the last parameter wich is a cron expression that says:

```
Run this job At 00:00:00am, every 14 days starting on the 1st, every month
```

If you want to create another cron expression I would suggest this online generator:

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: I get "Cron expression is invalid" with that CRON string